# Sprites will not reappear in same position after a timer

Tags: pygame, instance, sprite

So I have fixed the issue where a platform disappears after a certain time when player is stood on it without removing all instances, but now need to make the platform reappear after a certain time so player can progress.

I have tried creating instance and adding to group again in the game loop and in the code shown below adding a new timer, but nothing happens. If I add to group after this code the platfroms don;t disappear, so I assume the adding sprite to group is working, I just can't get a time delay on it re-appearing.

```
if self.rect.bottom == trick_platform.rect.top -1:
                        trick_platform.timer += 1
                        if trick_platform.timer > 24:
                            trick_platform.kill()
```

The instance originates when world is drawn in tile '24' as below in world class...

```
elif tile == 24:#create trick_platform
                    trick_platform = TrickPlatform(x * TILESIZE, y * TILESIZE)
                    trick_platform_group.add(trick_platform)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) remove the Sprite from all Groups. This means the Sprite object gets destroyed an cannot "reappear".

I suggest to use 2 [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Groupv) objects. One for the visible platforms and one for the invisible platforms.

```py
trick_platform_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
invisble_platform_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Remove the platform form the `trick_platform_group` *Group* and add it to the `invisble_platform_group` *Group* when it becomes invisible:

```py
trick_platform_group.remove(trick_platform)
invisble_platform_group.add(trick_platform)
```

Do the opposite when it becomes visible again

```py
trick_platform_group.add(trick_platform)
invisble_platform_group.remove(trick_platform)
```